# How does one install VS2008 on Vista?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-vista

I met a lot of problems when I'm trying to compile with VS2008 on Vista. Because I'm new to VS2008 and new to programming in Windows, I'm totally lost when errors happen.

My problem is as following:

The vs2008 has anyway been installed and I tried to build a open source app 
and the compilation stopped due to errors. In the output window I see:

> 1>fatal error C1900: Il mismatch between 'P1' version '20080116' and 'P2' version '20070207'

Totally mess for me!!!

Comment: You need to include what errors you are encountering, or some sort of description of what you have been trying or nobody is going to be able to help you.

Comment: It would help if you said what the errors were. After all, normally it "just works"

Comment: Are you running VS with administrator priviledges? If not, Shift+Right click on its icon and choose run as administrator, or permanently check the run as administrator on the icon's file properties.

Comment: @Cecil: you don't need to run VS with admin privileges in most scenarios. I've been running as a limited user for several years now (on Windows 2003, 2008, Vista and 7) and I've only had problems when trying to debug services or IIS-hosted web apps. All of which are easily worked around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a thread on this error: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/9abfefe0-56bd-4a82-ae14-b08f262972bd

Sounds like you need to install [VS2008 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en). You should probably also make sure you're up to date with the latest .NET releases.

Answer (score 0):

P1 and P2 refer to the "passes" made by the compiler over your code. Microsoft's C++ compiler is a two-pass compiler. The first pass generates data (in some kind of intermediate form) that's given to the second pass for actual conversion to machine code.

These are implemented in c1.dll and c2.dll.

The error is essentially complaining that you've got mismatched versions. Try a repair install, or install VS2008 Service Pack 1.